# Gitlab runner ECS fargate build docker images

Tags: docker, gitlab, aws-fargate

I have moved my gitlab-runner infrastructure to `AWS` ecs `fargate` and now it is working fine.

But I have problem,

I have a `.gitlab-ci.yml` file and has following commands:

```
stages:
  - RUN_TESTS

build-docker:
  stage: RUN_TESTS
  script:
    - echo "Running the tests..."
    - ls
    - docker build -t test .
  only:
```

But since `fargate` gitlab runner doesn't support `docker-in-docker`, I used a `node` image to install docker while installing the gitlab-runner fargate driver.

as below:

```
FROM node:14

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Install https://github.com/krallin/tini - a very small 'init' process
# that helps processing signalls sent to the container properly.
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------
ARG TINI_VERSION=v0.19.0

RUN curl -Lo /usr/local/bin/tini https://github.com/krallin/tini/releases/download/${TINI_VERSION}/tini-amd64 \
    && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/tini

# --------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Install and configure sshd.
# https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/running_ssh_service for reference.
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y openssh-server \
    && mkdir -p /var/run/sshd

EXPOSE 22

# ----------------------------------------
# Install GitLab CI required dependencies.
# ----------------------------------------
ARG GITLAB_RUNNER_VERSION=v12.9.0

RUN curl -Lo /usr/local/bin/gitlab-runner https://gitlab-runner-downloads.s3.amazonaws.com/${GITLAB_RUNNER_VERSION}/binaries/gitlab-runner-linux-amd64 \
    && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/gitlab-runner

RUN curl -s https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/github/git-lfs/script.deb.sh | bash \
    && apt-get install git-lfs \
    && git lfs install --skip-repo

RUN apt-get update && \
apt-get install -yq gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 \
libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 \
libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 \
libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 \
ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils wget


# INSTALL DOCKER 
# RUN apt-get remove docker docker-engine docker.io containerd runc
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install  \
    apt-transport-https \
    ca-certificates \
    curl \
    gnupg-agent \
    software-properties-common
RUN curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | apt-key add -    
RUN apt-key fingerprint 0EBFCD88
RUN add-apt-repository \
   "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian \
   $(lsb_release -cs) \
   stable"
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io -y

RUN docker --version


# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Execute a startup script.
# https://success.docker.com/article/use-a-script-to-initialize-stateful-container-data
# for reference.
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["tini", "--", "/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

But this gives the error:

> Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

Is there a way I can bypass this nature in ecs gitlab runner fargate?

Comment: Did you found a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Kaniko](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/kaniko/blob/master/README.md) to build Docker images without Docker. This is a standalone build tool for docker files. Kaniko's sole purpose is building container images, so it is best run in it's own GitLab task.

```
stages:
  - RUN_TESTS

build-docker:
  image: gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:debug-v0.11.0
  stage: RUN_TESTS
  script:
    - echo "Running the tests..."
    - ls
    - /kaniko/executor
         --context $CI_PROJECT_DIR/
         --dockerfile $CI_PROJECT_DIR/Dockerfile
         --no-push
```

The `--no-push` Tells kaniko not to save the resulting container image anywhere. This is suitable for using it to run tests. Otherwise the Kaniko documentation has lots of information on [pushing to a suitable registry](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/kaniko/blob/master/README.md#pushing-to-different-registries).

Comment: According to the [gitlab manual](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/runner_autoscale_aws_fargate/#step-7-test-the-configuration),

`The image and service keywords in your gitlab-ci.yml file are ignored. The runner only uses the values specified in the task definition.`

Indeed I could not use kaniko image in the task executed in fargate autoscaling gitlab runner.
Have not tried but specifying kaniko image in fargate task definition could be a solution.

Comment: @Satoshi, you are correct. Thanks.